# Gentle(-er) Introduction to Erdős–Bollobás's solution to Ramsey–Turán Type Problem

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, extremal-graph-theory

I am currently trying to understand the construction of maximal graph which contains no $K_4$ and sub-linear number of independent points in the graph. The original paper [On a Ramsey–Turán type problem](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(76)90057-5), although ground-breaking, is very hard to parse. It also glosses over some crucial details and claims some really non-trivial identities. I am listing some of them below (but there are probably more questions one can ask).

- Is there a way to partition a hyper-sphere of dimension $n$ into $N$ equal parts and bounded diameters?
- Aren't $C$ and $A$, as defined in the paper, very close to each other? Importantly, doesn't that imply that $\delta > 1$ (and that's it)?
- Can anyone explain the argument made to find the diameter of the spherical cap that, as claimed on top of page 3?

Comment: Note: Erdős's name is spelled with ő ("o with double acute"), not ö ("o with diaeresis").  I have edited accordingly.  I also edited out an institutionally gated link to the article, and replaced it with a DOI link.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you, I forgot about the gated link :)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456512/gentle-er-introduction-to-erd%c5%91s-bollob%c3%a1ss-solution-to-ramsey-tur%c3%a1n-type-probl#comment1182342_456512), no worries.  Is there a missing word or words in your third bullet point ("… the diameter of the spherical cap that, as claimed …")?

Comment: An alternative presentation of the Bollobás-Erdős construction appears in this paper by Balogh and Lenz (sections 3, 4) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4428.pdf

Comment: Name of the paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456512/gentle-er-introduction-to-erd%c5%91s-bollob%c3%a1ss-solution-to-ramsey-tur%c3%a1n-type-probl#comment1182811_456512) by @hdur: [Balogh and Lenz - On the Ramsey–Turán numbers of graphs and hypergraphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4428).

Comment: @hdur The paper still runs into the same problem. To start of with, how do I show you can divide an unit sphere into equal parts of bounded diameter?

Answer (score 2):

I found an excellent account of this problem in the thesis of John Lenz: [xtremal graph theory: Ramsey-Turán numbers, chromatic thresholds, and minors
Lenz, John E.](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/items/24855)